# Sliver navigation flutter for Spotify like appearance

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was listening to music on Spotify, and started wondering how to get the exact animation shown in the Artist page.

It includes sliver navigation, but also text on top of the artist image (maybe a simple stack would work)
Also there's a floating action widget (shuffle play) and, my favourite, the artist image ZOOMS back when scrolled up!
I want to recreate it on Flutter.

Can anyone help me?

[image: Spotify artist image]

Comment: read this it could help https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-sliverappbar-examples

Comment: and this https://www.filledstacks.com/snippet/collapsable-toolbar-in-flutter-using-slivers/

Comment: The appbar title is reappearing - read this https://medium.com/@eibaan_54644/reappearing-app-bar-titles-eff8b35f6826.And for the shuffle play button, it is a persistentHeader — https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe

Comment: The shuffle play button link isn't working for some reason! Thanks for everything else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't use Spotify.
but I hope It could give good beginning.

[image]

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

double _appTopBarHeight = 60;
String artistName = 'Dennis Lloyd';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverPersistentHeader(
          delegate: MyDelegate(),
          floating: true,
          pinned: true,
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (_, index) => Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(index.toString()),
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text('Title'),
                          Text('Subtitle'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.more_vert,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            childCount: 100,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  @override
  Widget build(_, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    var shrinkPercentage =
        min(1, shrinkOffset / (maxExtent - minExtent)).toDouble();

    return Stack(
      overflow: Overflow.clip,
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: Container(
            height: _appTopBarHeight,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  Opacity(
                    opacity: 1 - shrinkPercentage,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 900,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                        alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                        image: NetworkImage(
                            'https://66.media.tumblr.com/c063f0b98040e8ec4b07547263b8aa15/tumblr_inline_ppignaTjX21s9on4d_540.jpg'),
                      )),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
            )
          ],
        ),
        Stack(
          overflow: Overflow.clip,
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: _appTopBarHeight,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_back,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: Opacity(
                              opacity: shrinkPercentage,
                              child: Text(
                                artistName,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.more_vert,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Opacity(
                    opacity: max(1 - shrinkPercentage * 6, 0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(height: 200),
                        Text(
                          artistName,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 48,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Subtitle',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    side: BorderSide(),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 5),
                    child: Text(
                      'SHUFFLE PLAY',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 400;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 110;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) => true;
}
```